# Which library path is used by default by GNU linker?

Tags: linker, embedded, arm, ld, toolchain

I'm using a toolchain and cross compiling for arm from i86 workstation. I know which path is using as a default path library the gnu linker of my workstation looking ld.config but i would like the default library directory for the gnu linker of my cross compiler. Sometimes, passing right LD_CFLAGS get errors like:

```
warning: libx***.so.0, needed by needed by liby***.so, not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i would like the default library directory for the gnu linker of my cross compiler

```
cross-gcc --print-search-dirs | grep ^libraries
```

should answer that for you.